# Product of tempered distribution is again a tempered distribution?

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I have the next doubts:

If $f$ is bounded and continuous function is a tempered distribution?

The product of two tempered distribution is again a tempered distribution?

Comment: Tempered distribution means continuous **linear** map $S \to \Bbb{C}$

Comment: My mistake Sorry I mean if a continuous and bounded function can be a temperate distribution (or can be identified with it)

Comment: Is $\phi \mapsto\ <f,\phi>\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \phi(x)dx$ well-defined, linear, continuous (for the Schwartz topology, that you need to define) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just work in $\mathbb{R},$ but it doesn't matter.

To answer your first question, note that if $\|f\|_\infty=M,$ then for any Schwartz function $\varphi$, 
\begin{align*}|\langle f,\varphi\rangle|&\leq\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)\varphi(x)|\, dx\leq M\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\varphi(x)|\, dx\\
&=M\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |\varphi(x)|\langle x\rangle^2 \langle x\rangle^{-2}\, dx\\
&\leq M\sup_x|\langle x\rangle^2\varphi(x)| \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \langle x\rangle^{-2}\, dx\\
&=M\pi \sup_x|\langle x\rangle^2\varphi(x)|\leq M\pi\|\varphi\|_2,\end{align*} where $ \langle x\rangle=(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}$, and $$\|\varphi\|_k=\sum\limits_{|\alpha|\leq k}\sup_x|  \langle x\rangle^k \partial^\alpha \varphi|$$ denotes the $k$th Schwartz semi-norm. So, the answer is yes, as this proves continuity (the only "difficult" thing to show). This is what @reuns is getting at with their comment. Also, this generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by putting an appropriate power of $\langle x\rangle$ (to make it integrable).

For multiplication, you'd need to be more clear as to what you mean when you talk about multiplying distributions.